# How to call play() of an <audio> element inside a component?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

What is the right way to call play on an audio element in AngularDart?
I know that I can use @ViewChild('audio') annotation to get ElementRef, but ElementRef is deprecated.

```
<div class="audio-controls">
    <material-fab raised (trigger)="onPlay()">
        <material-icon icon="play_arrow" ></material-icon>
    </material-fab>
</div>

<audio><source src="audio.ogg"></audio>
```

```
class AudioComponent {

  void onPlay() {
    //??
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just started learning AngualDart. I see now that this is wrong approach. I should use AudioContext to play audio or eventually, as a last resort, create AudioElement inside AudioComponent. AudioElement doesn't have to be added to a DOM tree (?).

Template should be used to define interface not logic (audio tag).